# How to resolve an invalid syntax error in Flask when trying to name?

Tags: json, flask, python-requests, api-design

So I am designing an API in flask and get invalid syntax when I try this:

```
 @summy.route('/api/summarize', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
# Get Data
articleUrl = request.json['articleUrl']
if not request.json or 'articleUrl' not in request.json:
        abort(400)
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I get the following error message:

> 'articleUrl' returns an invalid syntax error.

Please can someone help me with a solution.

Comment: write  #Get Data part in function and check. Also there is a space before @summy.

Answer (score 0):

Write #Get Data part in function. Also there is a space before @summy. The code will be :

```
@summy.route('/api/summarize', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def api():
    # Get Data
    articleUrl = request.json['articleUrl']
    if not request.json or 'articleUrl' not in request.json:
            abort(400)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```